# Detecting what section is the user currently looking at

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a small problem with figuring out how to detect what section is the user looking at or at least what section is covering most of the screen. I have my content like this: [On the left side I would like to see the name of the section (whatever the name is or the name of the section that is covering most of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1fFY.jpg)

I'm pretty sure that I saw some websites that use something similar to this but I was haven't been able to find them.

Did anyone want to do something similar? How did you go about doing that?

Comment: The term is [**scroll spy**](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+scroll+spy) I believe

Comment: scroll top + viewport's height + a bit of math

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you are right, that's exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!